# Initialisation of variables

Tags: coq

i am beginner with coq.
I have a question about a manipulation of variables, for example i have:
      Parameter x:nat.
I want to initialise x by 0 and after that i want affect 5 to x,so i didn't know how to do that?.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your question here ? Please explain what you have and what you want to do in a clear manner.

Answer (score 0):

Coq is a pure functional programming language. There are no mutable global variables. You can model state using the same trick Haskell uses: monads.